# Почему в данном коде закомментирование строки изменяет переменную находящуюся выше этого комментария?

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, python-3.7

Хочу протестировать функцию возвращающую аргументы "охватывающей" функции:

```
import inspect
import unittest


def outer_func_args() -> dict:
    """Get outer function arguments."""
    currframe = inspect.currentframe()
    callerframe = inspect.getouterframes(currframe, 2)
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(callerframe[1][0])
    return values


class TestOuterFuncArgs(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_(self):
        """Test function outer_func_args()."""
        def func(a, b, c, d):
            args = outer_func_args()
            # See print() result
            print("outer_func_args before assertEqual(): {}".format(args))
            r = {'a': 123, 'b': 45.56, 'c': "adc", "d": 23 + 4j}
            self.assertEqual(args, r)
        func(123, 45.56, "adc", 23 + 4j)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Запускаем скрипт.

Тест не пройден. Функция `print()`, вызванная перед методом `assertEqual` печатает следующее (обратите внимание на *наличие* `self`):

```
outer_func_args before assertEqual(): {'a': 123, 'b': 45.56, 'c': 'adc', 'd': (23+4j), 'self': <forstack.TestOuterFuncArgs testMethod=test_>}
```

Но если мы закомментируем метод `assertEqual()`:

```
class TestOuterFuncArgs(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_(self):
        """Test function outer_func_args()."""
        def func(a, b, c, d):
            args = outer_func_args()
            # See print() result later
            print("outer_func_args before assertEqual(): {}".format(args))
            r = {'a': 123, 'b': 45.56, 'c': "adc", "d": 23 + 4j}
            # self.assertEqual(args, r)
        func(123, 45.56, "adc", 23 + 4j)
```

то тогда функция `print()`, находящаяся на том же месте (перед `assertEqual()`, напечатает следующее  (обратите внимание на *отсутствие* `self`):

```
outer_func_args before assertEqual(): {}:  {'a': 123, 'b': 45.56, 'c': 'adc', 'd': (23+4j)}
```

Почему в данном коде закомментирование строки c `assertEqual()` изменяет переменную `args` находящуюся выше этого комментария, а именно добавляет/удаляет `self` из `args`?

Comment: Вместо всего assertEqual можно просто написать `self` — и проблема всё равно будет воспроизводиться. Видимо, это как-то связано с замыканием

Comment: Вообще, никто не обещал, что в `values` будут только аргументы. Согласно документации это «the locals dictionary of the given frame», в котором могут быть не только аргументы

Comment: Эту функцию я планировал вызывать сразу после инструкции `def` в другой функции, вследствие чего словарь `locals` был бы не засорен. Код уже переделан, в том смысле что ключи элементов словаря `locals` результата вызова функции `getargvalues()` проверяются на вхождение в список `args`. В этом случае все работает как надо и функцию `outer_func_args()` можно вызвать в любом месте другой функции. Однако в этом рабочем варианте, ясно, эффекта про который я спрашиваю, не наблюдается. Поэтому в вопросе используется первый вариант.